# Оптимизировать рекурсию js

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, рекурсия

Есть большой массив 70к объектов, нужно в соответствии массивом IDs, конечных узлов (1к элементов) вывести вложенный результирующий массив в виде дерева. Сделал через рекурсию, код отрабатывает ~8 сек. Пытался делать через цикл for + break не особо что-то изменилось, даже медленнее стало. Как ускорить?

```js
const arr = [
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: null,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Двигатель'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Двигатель в сборе'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 138,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Прокладка двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 139,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Подвеска двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Основные элементы двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 141,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Блок цилиндров и головка блока'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 142,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Картер масляный и крышки блока'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 143,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Вал коленчатый и маховик'
  },

  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1136,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: null,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Трансмиссия'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1137,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 1136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Трансмиссионый блок'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1138,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 1137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Шайба м8'
  },
]

const ids = [138, 140, 1138]


let result = [];

async function getTreeCategoriesByIds(ids) {

  function getPatch(ids) {
    arr.forEach(elem => {
      ids.forEach((id, index) => {
        if (elem.CATEGORY_ID === id) {
          result[index] = elem;
          if (elem.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID !== null) {
            recursive(elem.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID, index);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function recursive(parrentId, index) {
    arr.forEach(elem => {
      if (elem.CATEGORY_ID === parrentId) {
        result[index] = { ...elem, child: result[index] };
        if (elem.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID !== null) {
          recursive(elem.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID, index);
        }
      }
    });
  }
    getPatch(ids)

}

 getTreeCategoriesByIds(ids)

console.log( ...result );
```

Comment: Переложить их в Map что бы не бегать по массиву постоянно

Comment: бинарный поиск ? вы вообще уверены что у вас именно поиск долгий, а не в целом загрузка этого добра в память?

Comment: @teran хм, не уверен.

Comment: @АндрейИванов затестите по скорости все предложенные варианты решения для интереса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создал вспомогательный объект вида `{ CATEGORY_ID: obj, CATEGORY_ID: obj }` для быстрого нахождения объектов по `id`.

Без рекурсии, в цикле находить родителей и вложить текущий объект в родителя, условие: `while (CATEGORY_PARENT_ID)`

```js
const arr = [
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: null,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Двигатель'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Двигатель в сборе'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 138,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Прокладка двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 139,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Подвеска двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Основные элементы двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 141,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Блок цилиндров и головка блока'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 142,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Картер масляный и крышки блока'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 143,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Вал коленчатый и маховик'
  },

  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1136,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: null,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Трансмиссия'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1137,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 1136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Трансмиссионый блок'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1138,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 1137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Шайба м8'
  },
]

/***/
let elements = {};

arr.forEach(obj => {
  elements[obj.CATEGORY_ID] = obj;
});

function getTreeCategoriesByIds(ids) {
  return ids.map(id => {
    let obj = { ...elements[id] };

    while (obj.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID) {
      obj = { ...elements[obj.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID], child: obj };
    }

    return obj;
  });
}

/***/
const ids = [138, 140, 1138];
let result = getTreeCategoriesByIds(ids);

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: и в цикле еще убрать лишнее `obj = { ...elements[obj.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID], ...{ child: obj } }`

Comment: ~ 140ms стало! в сравнении с 8 секундами, нереальный прирост производительности. Спасибо большое, рекурсия - зло, походу)

Comment: @АндрейИванов рекурсия не зло. Вот бегать по массиву каждый раз в поисках родителя — зло.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Спасибо, исправлено)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а я сижу и голову ломаю. Даже все пересечения испробовал и понять не могу в чем разница.

Comment: кстати, в чём разница? по скорости как и было..

Comment: @АндрейИванов Ну было написано в 3 строчки, а можно было одной) Не сразу допер. По скорости - никакой разницы.

Answer (score 2):

Вариация с бинарным поиском (в предположении, что ваш массив таки отсортирован изначально по возрастанию id, а также, что искомые данные гарантированно в массиве есть).

По сравнению с прочими вариантами не требует лишней памяти для хранения словаря, не требует операций по перебору всего массива для построения этого самого словаря. получим наименьшее время работы, раз уж мы тут про оптимизацию говорим.

за основу взят соседний ответ @Grundy

```js
const arr = [{CATEGORY_ID:136,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:null,CATEGORY_NAME:'Двигатель'},{CATEGORY_ID:137,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:136,CATEGORY_NAME:'Двигатель в сборе'},{CATEGORY_ID:138,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:137,CATEGORY_NAME:'Прокладка двигателя'},{CATEGORY_ID:139,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:137,CATEGORY_NAME:'Подвеска двигателя'},{CATEGORY_ID:140,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:136,CATEGORY_NAME:'Основные элементы двигателя'},{CATEGORY_ID:141,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:140,CATEGORY_NAME:'Блок цилиндров и головка блока'},{CATEGORY_ID:142,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:140,CATEGORY_NAME:'Картер масляный и крышки блока'},{CATEGORY_ID:143,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:140,CATEGORY_NAME:'Вал коленчатый и маховик'},{CATEGORY_ID:1136,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:null,CATEGORY_NAME:'Трансмиссия'},{CATEGORY_ID:1137,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:1136,CATEGORY_NAME:'Трансмиссионый блок'},{CATEGORY_ID:1138,CATEGORY_PARENT_ID:1137,CATEGORY_NAME:'Шайба м8'},];

const ids = [138, 140, 1138];

function search(a, id) {
  let s = 0, e = a.length - 1;
  
  while(true){  
    let m = Math.floor(s + (e-s)/2);        
    if (a[m].CATEGORY_ID == id) return a[m];    
    a[m].CATEGORY_ID > id ? e = m-1 : s = m+1;           
  }
}


function getPath(id) {
  var cur = search(arr, id);
  while (cur.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID != null) {
    cur = { ...search(arr, cur.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID),
      child: cur
    };
  }
  return cur;
}


console.log( ids.map(i => getPath(i)) );
```

Потенциально, если надо не просто найти пути для "трех"  узлов, а постоянно дергать и искать разные, то сей поиск надо скрестить со словарем для "кэширования" уже найденных вариантов. Если же предполагается, что число вершин (с учетом родительских) будет одного порядка с размером самого массива, то тут проще сразу словарь использовать.

Comment: на счет наименьшего времени работы - спорно. По сути, со словарем время работы возрастает линейно, в то время как с использованием поиска, пусть и бинарного, логарифмически

Comment: @Grundy если понадобится найти пути для M-вершин. то это потребует условно `m*x` итераций (где x - длина пути), а не перебора всего массива с формирование словаря.

Comment: не понял комментарий :)

Comment: @Grundy ты чтобы словарь построить все 70к элементов массива переберешь изначально. с поиском (по данным трем id) потребуется просмотреть пару десятков индексов массива, а не 70к.

Comment: Да, почти, только тут все начинает зависеть дополнительно от длины пути, в то время как со словарем, зависимость только от количества элементов :) По хорошему нужно бы замерить на нескольких работах данных :) ну и киллер фича - словарь не требует отсортированности :)

Comment: замерил, время выполнения этого блока кода занимает ~17ms, а самое первое решение ~5ms. Возможно, с бинарным поиском на очень больших данных выиграет.

Comment: ещё бы потребление памяти замерить, но я этого не умею(

Comment: @АндрейИванов, у тебя id отсортированы в массиве? Для измерения лучше что-то вроде jsperf.com использовать

Comment: @АндрейИванов это на 70к объектах? и что есть "самое первое"?

Comment: @Grundy да, отсортированы, я их из монго получаю .sort({ CATEGORY_ID: 1 }).distinct('CATEGORY_ID').lean().exec();

Comment: @Grundy да, про это у меня абзац после кода и написан. будет эффективно для определенных сценариев использования.

Comment: @teran самое первое, которое OPTIMUS PRIME написал, да там 69879 объектов

Comment: @АндрейИванов там в комментах у вас просто 140мс написано

Comment: @teran это я лишнее мерил, запрос ещё прихватил. Сейчас строго только этот блок кода.

Comment: @АндрейИванов "потребление памяти" зависит от того, сколько весят ключи объектов и указатели на другие объекты. Не смог найти, но можно примерно прикинуть. Гугл говорит, указатель в C++ занимает до 8 байтов. Если ключи считать строками из 5 символов, это еще 10 байтов, 18 * 70к = порядка 1 МБ.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы каждый раз не искать родителя/детей необходимо произвести подготовку массива и свернуть его в объект, где ключом является `CATEGORY_ID`, и значением сам объект. Это позволит находить объекты быстрее.

Далее достаточно будет функции, которая по конечному ID пройдет по всем PARENT_ID и построит искомый объект

выглядеть она может так:

```
function getPath(id, map) {
  var cur = map[id];
  while (cur.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID != null) { // если родитель NULL - дошли до верха и можно выходить
    cur = { ...map[cur.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID], // формируем объект
      child: cur
    };
  }
  return cur;
}
```

Конечный код может выглядеть так:

```js
const arr = [{
    CATEGORY_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: null,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Двигатель'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Двигатель в сборе'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 138,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Прокладка двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 139,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Подвеска двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Основные элементы двигателя'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 141,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Блок цилиндров и головка блока'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 142,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Картер масляный и крышки блока'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 143,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 140,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Вал коленчатый и маховик'
  },

  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1136,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: null,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Трансмиссия'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1137,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 1136,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Трансмиссионый блок'
  },
  {
    CATEGORY_ID: 1138,
    CATEGORY_PARENT_ID: 1137,
    CATEGORY_NAME: 'Шайба м8'
  },
]

const ids = [138, 140, 1138]

function createMap(a) {
  return a.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.CATEGORY_ID] = cur;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function getPath(id, map) {
  var cur = map[id];
  while (cur.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID != null) {
    cur = { ...map[cur.CATEGORY_PARENT_ID],
      child: cur
    };
  }
  return cur;
}

const map = createMap(arr)

console.log(ids.map(i => getPath(i, map)));
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение очень наглядно! теперь понял фишку с arr[key] =)

Comment: объект на 70к ключей себя нормально чувстует?

Comment: @teran, а почему нет?:) вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46051840/2881286) говорят что до нескольких миллионов ключей можно :-) в 2017 году

Comment: @Grundy там в соседнем про 116млн написано ) зы: запостил с бинарным поиском, шустрее будет

Comment: @teran, это для целочисленных ключей было :) там в комментариях есть что если добавить в ключ строку - то опускается до 8.3 опять :)